# реализация алгоритма diff3

Tags: алгоритм

Я пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм diff3, уже разобрался как получать LCS между файлом-предком и "моим" файлом и LCS между файлом-предком и "сторонним" файлом. Дальше нужно получить "стабильные" и "нестабильные" куски (chunks), и я пока не пойму, как это делается. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.